# Why does Selenium ExecuteScript method doesn't work anymore in Salesforce application but ExecuteAsyncScript works

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce, selenium-chromedriver, salesforce-lightning

Hi I've been trying to figure this for the past couple of days.  I wrote the code below that use to work but doesn't work any more using the ExecuteScript method.  The only thing i have changed was update my chrome driver because it was not launching chrome since the driver wasn't working with the older chrome version I have. So once I updated the chrome driver it began to work until i had to run this piece of code.  I modified it below not to what the actual link text is.

```
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)WebActions.One;
            js.ExecuteScript("alert('Welcome to Guru99');"); // This was added for testing purpose
            IWebElement somelink = WebActions.One.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Some Text']"));
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", somelink );
```

When i changed the method to be ExecuteAsyncScript it started working again. Is this something that has changed with the app or is this something i'm doing wrong.  I tried reading up on ExecuteAsyncScript vs ExecuteScript to see the difference but all i was able to get was something about the call back telling 
when its finished which i'm not experienced in java script.

I would just like to understand more then anything or should i just start using ExecuteAsyncScript method.  Thanks

Comment: I think the async version just creates an anonymous function and accepts a 2nd argument for a callback.  (for success/fail)  What error do you receive when calling the standard ExecuteScript call?

Comment: You probably just imagined that it worked again. This won't work either way because the alert will block the click. I can't see what your ExecuteAsyncScript looks like so I really can't tell.

Comment: @pcalkins I don't seem to receive any blocking exceptions  when i use the standard ExecuteScript, the script execute and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: hard to tell without actual markup and script... can you post that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a chromedriver ticket about this issue here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3103

It states:

> The cause of the issue is this website modifies the constructor of the
>   built-in AsyncFunction object. This causes difficulty when
>   ChromeDriver tries to create an AsyncFunction to wrap the script being
>   executed.

chromedriver 78 fixes the issue. For testing with Chrome 77, the ticket recommends switching to executeAsyncScript, or using chromedriver 76 since "ChromeDriver vX will run with Chrome vX+1".

Comment: Thanks @randy I'm glad it wasn't me.  I thought i was losing it. In the mean time i came up with a work around to fix the issue.